# How do you remove the clock time from the menu bar in macOS?

Tags: macos, big-sur, menu-bar, monterey

In macOS Big Sur and Monterey, the clock in the menu bar now toggles Notification Center.

I use iStat Menu to display the clock in the menu bar, and it looks bad having two times visible:

[image: iStat Menu Clock + stock macOS clock in menu bar]

Is there a way to re-add the dedicated Notification Center menu bar icon, as existed in Catalina and previous versions of macOS?

How can I remove the time and clock from the modern macOS menu bar?

Comment: For reference, my Apple report: https://github.com/feedback-assistant/reports/issues/131

Comment: Not a response to the question, but what I did was to change my Stats config so that it doesn't display the time

Comment: I agree with  @finitud - why turn off an OS feature because of a third-party thing that does exactly the same? If iStat can turn off its clock, then do that. It's not like it's a 'better' clock or more accurate.

Comment: @benwiggy The iStat Menus clock has much more control over the date and time format it displays. It also has a handy configurable dropdown showing a month-by-month calendar, the current time at selected cities, calendar entries, and/or other stuff you select. So yes, there are reasons why you might want it instead of the system clock.

Answer (score 54):

The clock is no longer optional for Big Sur and newer macOS. It drives the do not disturb shortcut (option + select) and summons the [Notification Center](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204079) when selected.

To minimize screen area, select the analog clock icon preference for the menu bar:

> System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar > Clock > Time Options > Analog

This is not what you want as per the title, as it removes the *text of the time* from the menu bar, but as per the question's description, it does set Big Sur notification to a single (clock) icon.

[image: Analogue clock]

In terminal.app, this preference can be scripted or set from the command line:

```
defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock IsAnalog -bool true
```

Answer (score 12):

There's no way to do it now because the time serves as the button for showing the notification center and the widget view. Hope it gets fixed in the future.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132663/discussion-on-answer-by-fere-how-do-you-remove-the-clock-time-from-the-menu-bar).

Answer (score 9):

I also use (and LOVE!) iStat Menus. Best solution is to display the date with iStat and the time with the system. Decent compromise.

[image]